# How to flush all session in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to flush all user sessions after a migration, but the session keep persists even after I had try

- `session()->flush();`
- `Session::flush();`

Any idea how should I remove all the session? will deleting all the files in storage/framework/sessions help?

Comment: In the logout in my Auth controller I use   \Session::flush();  see if that works for you.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using file based session then you have to delete all files from **storage/framework/sessions** & **`null`** **remember_token** field from users table

Comment: Just delete all files from storage/framework/sessions works for me. Thanks